# ¿Por qué input no se ajusta al contenedor, teniendo atributo size y max-width?

Tags: css, input, size

Estoy trabajando en un diseño responsivo y tengo algunos *input* con atributo *size* variables, dependiendo del contenido. Al aplicar *max-width* no funciona, haciendo crecer al contenedor, incluso con porcentaje menor a 100, como se ve en esta imagen:

[image: Fieldset crece por el input]

> **Nota:** Para este ejemplo estoy usando una medida fija (en pixeles) para el contenedor, sin embargo, con *media queries* la medida final es en porcentaje, tanto contenedor como *input*.

Al menos en *Firefox* pasa con este fragmento de código:

```css
fieldset {
    width:400px;
    margin:20px auto;
}
.texto-max {
    /* Se muestra con el tamaño especificado (¿?), */
    /* pero "reserva" espacio al final */
    /* haciendo crecer al contenedor */
    max-width:80%;
}
.texto {
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Prueba</legend>
  <input type="text" name="texto" size="80" class="texto-max" placeholder="Clase texto-max">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Prueba</legend>
  <input type="text" name="texto" size="80" class="texto" placeholder="Clase texto">
</fieldset>
```

Asignando un ancho fijo (*width*) podría funcionar, a reserva de revisar todos los formularios del sitio, donde aparecen campos en columnas o uno al lado de otro.

Leyendo la respuesta de [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41409621/can-css-over-rule-html-input-size-declarations) veo que *max-width* puede funcionar usando medidas relativas al *viewport*, pero necesito que se adapte al contenedor.

¿Hay alguna solución sin recurrir a *Javascript* ni modificar el atributo *size*?

Comment: Hola, en este caso, ya que el contenedor sí tiene un ancho fijo, podrías ponerle directamente el max-width en 320px (80% de 400px) y ahí sí funciona

Comment: Muchas gracias, @EricaT., no había considerado esa posibilidad, sin embargo, al trabajar con diseño responsivo, llega un punto donde el contenedor queda al 100% del ancho disponible y ya no es viable usar medidas en pixeles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los navegadores tienen CSS personalizado para ciertos los elementos.
Por ejemplo:

- `Chrome` tiene para los `fieldset` un [`min-inline-size: min-content;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/min-inline-size)

### Solución:

Basta con establecer [`min-inline-size: 0;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-inline-size) o [`min-width: 0;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/min-width) para solucionar tu problema.

```css
fieldset {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  min-inline-size: 0;
}
.texto-max {
  max-width: 80%;
}
.texto {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Prueba</legend>
  <input type="text" name="texto" size="80" class="texto-max" placeholder="Clase texto-max">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Prueba</legend>
  <input type="text" name="texto" size="80" class="texto" placeholder="Clase texto">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Excelente, es una solución muy sencilla y me ahorraste muchos dolores de cabeza. ¡Gracias! Probado en Firefox, Chrome y derivados.